# Design Considerations

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

My company has used spreadsheets in the past to track services by building address. We track 4 service types and maintain columns such as Service year, Proposal Creation Date, Service amount, Contract Received Date, PO, and several others. There are often multiple buildings per contact.

We separate each service type by year and group tracking columns by service year. The spreadsheet is unwieldy and very difficult to manage. I used SharePoint decades ago and feel it could add meet our needs.

My question is how to approach the creation of this list. Is it better to have all the same columns and create different views or have several lists that can be used as lookups. I did separate contacts to an independent list so we may add multiple contacts to a single building.

Ideally, I wish to review a single building and determine what we have completed in past years, what is projected to be completed in the current year along with pricing, and what is in progress or completed.

Forgive my ignorance if this is not suitable for this forum.

Answer (score 0):

In order to facilitate management and avoid too many lists, in this case, I suggest you use a list with the same columns and create different views to achieve your needs.

For example, if you want to review a building and determine the projects you have completed in the past few years and projects to be completed this year, you can create a view based on the Service year column in the list; what is in progress or completed, you can create a service status column in a table and filter items based on that column to create a view.